# Adding filters to data views with IEnumerable functions

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am working on customization to add some filters to the existing data view.
The **Activity** data view on the Employee Time Activities page.
I have added the Customer property to `PMTimeActivity` and `OwnedFilter`.
Now I need to modify the `activity` method to take into consideration the Customer filter.
The only way to do this is to override the method with one of the following scenarios:

- without calling the base method and copying the code and adding the
  filter part
- with calling the base method and checking the condition on each
  returned record.

The first scenario is making this part of customization very problematic because it will require to review this code every time the customization is being upgraded to any other build.

The second scenario is not good from a performance view.

Has anybody faced this issue and how can this be done in an acceptable way?

Below is the code of the `activity` method:

```
    protected virtual IEnumerable activity()
    {
        List<object> args = new List<object>();
        EmployeeActivitiesEntry.PMTimeActivityFilter filterRow = this.Filter.Current;
        if (filterRow == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        BqlCommand cmd = BqlCommand.CreateInstance(new Type[]
        {
            typeof(Select2<EPActivityApprove, LeftJoin<EPEarningType, On<EPEarningType.typeCD, Equal<PMTimeActivity.earningTypeID>>, LeftJoin<CRActivityLink, On<CRActivityLink.noteID, Equal<PMTimeActivity.refNoteID>>, LeftJoin<CRCase, On<CRCase.noteID, Equal<CRActivityLink.refNoteID>>, LeftJoin<ContractEx, On<CRCase.contractID, Equal<ContractEx.contractID>>>>>>, Where<EPActivityApprove.ownerID, Equal<Current<EmployeeActivitiesEntry.PMTimeActivityFilter.ownerID>>, And<EPActivityApprove.trackTime, Equal<True>, And<PMTimeActivity.isCorrected, Equal<False>>>>, OrderBy<Desc<EPActivityApprove.date>>>)
        });
        if (filterRow.ProjectID != null)
        {
            cmd = cmd.WhereAnd<Where<EPActivityApprove.projectID, Equal<Current<EmployeeActivitiesEntry.PMTimeActivityFilter.projectID>>>>();
        }
        if (filterRow.ProjectTaskID != null)
        {
            cmd = cmd.WhereAnd<Where<EPActivityApprove.projectTaskID, Equal<Current<EmployeeActivitiesEntry.PMTimeActivityFilter.projectTaskID>>>>();
        }
        if (filterRow.FromWeek != null || filterRow.TillWeek != null)
        {
            List<Type> cmdList = new List<Type>();
            bool? includeReject = filterRow.IncludeReject;
            bool flag = true;
            if (includeReject.GetValueOrDefault() == flag & includeReject != null)
            {
                cmdList.Add(typeof(Where<, , >));
                cmdList.Add(typeof(EPActivityApprove.approvalStatus));
                cmdList.Add(typeof(Equal<ActivityStatusListAttribute.rejected>));
                cmdList.Add(typeof(Or<>));
            }
            if (filterRow.FromWeek != null)
            {
                if (filterRow.TillWeek != null)
                {
                    cmdList.Add(typeof(Where<, , >));
                }
                else
                {
                    cmdList.Add(typeof(Where<, >));
                }
                cmdList.Add(typeof(EPActivityApprove.weekID));
                cmdList.Add(typeof(GreaterEqual<Required<EmployeeActivitiesEntry.PMTimeActivityFilter.fromWeek>>));
                args.Add(filterRow.FromWeek);
                if (filterRow.TillWeek != null)
                {
                    cmdList.Add(typeof(And<>));
                }
            }
            if (filterRow.TillWeek != null)
            {
                cmdList.Add(typeof(Where<EPActivityApprove.weekID, LessEqual<Required<EmployeeActivitiesEntry.PMTimeActivityFilter.tillWeek>>>));
                args.Add(filterRow.TillWeek);
            }
            cmd = cmd.WhereAnd(BqlCommand.Compose(cmdList.ToArray()));
        }
        return new PXView(this, false, cmd).SelectMultiBound(new object[]
        {
            this.Filter.Current
        }, args.ToArray());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider to try work with PXView, which was described by Sergey [here](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/06/using-pxview-in-dataview-delegate.html).

In case of Employee activities time card it may look like this:

```
public class EmployeeExt : PXGraphExtension<EmployeeActivitiesEntry>
{
    protected virtual IEnumerable activity()
    {
        var sel = new PXView(Base, true, Base.Activity.View.BqlSelect);

        if(true)
        {
            sel.WhereAnd<Where<EPActivityApprove.projectID, Equal<Current<EmployeeActivitiesEntry.PMTimeActivityFilter.projectID>>>>();
        }

        int totalRow = 0;
        int startRow = PXView.StartRow;

        return sel.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters,
            PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings,
            PXView.Filters, ref startRow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try and confirm the answer.

Comment: This approach is not working for the Views with delegates. The `sel` view has only filtering defined in the Data View declaration.